# JSF 2.2 Custom Component

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets, custom-component

I have a small JSF 2.2 webapp. Now I need a custom component, which simply displays on the page the following text:

Created by Nazar Sobchuk - 12/07/2013 (current date)

I have the following class for the component:

```
package com.dataart.mediaportal.components;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.faces.component.FacesComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter;

@FacesComponent(value = "components.FooterComponent", createTag = true)
public class FooterComponent extends UIComponentBase {

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return "my.custom.component";
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String date = dateFormat.format(new java.util.Date());

            ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
            writer.write("Created by Nazar Sobchuk - 2013");
            writer.write(date);
    }
}
```

How am I supposed to use this component on my JSF pages? What xmlns url should be included in order to use a component?

Here are web.xml and faces-config.xml files if needed:

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!--        
        responsible for handling multipart/form-data requests which 
        is required to be able to send files over HTTP.
        <servlet-name> must match the exact <servlet-name> 
        of the FacesServlet as you've definied in web.xml.
    -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ImgLoaderServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.dataart.mediaportal.servlet.ImgLoaderServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ImgLoaderServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/load</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>pages/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/pages/login.xhtml</from-view-id>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>home</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/home.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>register</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/registration.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>

    </navigation-rule>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/pages/registration.xhtml</from-view-id>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>home</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/home.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>registration</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/registration.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>

    </navigation-rule>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/pages/index.xhtml</from-view-id>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>

    </navigation-rule>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/pages/home.xhtml</from-view-id>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>

    </navigation-rule>

    <application>

        <message-bundle>
            AppErrorMessages
        </message-bundle>

        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>ru</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>

        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>i18n.MediaPortal</base-name>
            <var>bundle</var>
        </resource-bundle>

    </application>

</faces-config>
```

I would be eternally thankful for the solution. 
Nazar

Comment: Have you tried with composite components ? It should be easier. Just call some utility bean in it for the date. http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved the problem.If anyone has the same trouble - solution is below. This tutorial was especially helpful. 

http://myjavabuddy.blogspot.com/2013/04/writing-custom-components-for-jsf-20.html

Comment: This is a clumsy approach. A template file, or include file or maybe tag file was been easier. Note that the blog article which you linked assumes JSF 2.0 while JSF 2.2 offers ways to do it with less or even no XML.